# How to correctly parse html response in Postman

Tags: html, postman

I'm getting the response in html. All tutorials are using:

```
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('mw-search-result-heading');
```

or

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
```

and they both fail.

First one due to document not defined, second because response is not JSON but HTML.

So, how can I correctly parse an html in Postman ?

Comment: Try this
https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/request/9215231-cb2b07be-5a54-4450-b629-f2ea5db2e273

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/) jQuery api

Example:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text();
console.log($("title").text()); // get title
```